# Android: Setting background color of a selected date in CalendarView (NOT DatePicker)?

Tags: android, android-layout

Is there a way in which I can specify a custom background color of a selected date in a `CalendarView`, as circled in red in the screenshot below?

[image]

**Note**: I am using a `CalendarView`, not a `DatePicker`.

Comment: Doesn't this color change based on colorAccent's theme value?

Comment: Whoops, sorry, retracted my close vote.  You're right, this isn't a duplicate.